# How can I remove string before "#"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, string, nsstring

There is a string.

> NSString *test =  @"1997#test"

I want to remove string before "#". 
And it changes like this :

> NSString *test = @"test"

Can you help me?

Comment: Is there only ever going to be a single hash/pound (#) symbol in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically removing the string before `#` would leave you with "#test".

Anyway, use [`- [NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

```
test = [[test componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"] lastObject];
```

Note that this approach is fragile: if you you have 2 `#` you will end up with just the last part, e.g. "foo" from "abc#bar#foo".

Using `lastObject` instead of `objectAtIndex:` means if there is no `#` in the string then you get the original string instead of crashing.

Answer (score 3):

Using the standard [NSString API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) methods:

```
NSString* test = @"1997#test";
NSArray* parts = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSString* result = [parts count] > 1 ? [parts objectAtIndex: 1] : [parts objectAtIndex: 0];
```

Or if that's a little too obtuse (which personally I think it is), you can use the [NSString+JavaAPI](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/541) category and then do:

```
NSString* test = @"1997#test";
NSString* result = [test substringFromIndex: [test indexOf:@"#"] + 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is better than the other ways, but I was curios to see if I could do this without the *componentsSeparatedByString* and *objectAtIndex*.

```
NSString* oldString = @"1976#test";
int stringLocation = [oldString rangeOfString:@"#" ].location +1 ;
NSString* newString =[oldString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (stringLocation,[oldString length] -  stringLocation )];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *components=[test componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSString *test=[components objectAtIndex:1];
```

it will help you

Comment: There's a minor typo in your code snippet. ("NSSting" instead of NSString on the second line.) :-)

Answer (score 0):

If there's only ever going to be a single hash symbol in the string, you could simply use the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) `componentsSeparatedByString` method to return an array and then simply pluck the first element of the array into the string.

For example:

```
NSString *test = @"1997#test";
NSArray *stringComponents = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSString *test = [stringComponents objectAtIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString *test = @"Chetan#iPhone#test";

NSArray *stringComponents = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];

for (int i = 0; i < [stringComponents count]; i++)

{

```
 NSString *test = [stringComponents objectAtIndex:i];

 if ([test isEqualToString:@"test"] == true)

 {

      NSLog(@"found");

      break;

 }
```

}